# [Python - Tkinter]: button 1 creates a widget, button 2 needs to access it. Is there a way to do this without using a global variable?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I have 2 buttons.

`button_step_1` needs to be able to create an entry box, and `button_step_2` needs to be able to access the entry from `button_step_1`.

I have it set up like this because I'm going to need a function to create a number `n` of entry boxes, where `n` is determined from the properties of a file opened by `function_1`. The user will enter a value for the `Entry` between pressing `button_1` and pressing `button_2`, so the entry would ideally be retrieved upon pressing `button_2`.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(window)



def function_1():
    global some_string_entry 

    some_string_entry = tk.Entry(frame)
    some_string_entry.pack()


def function_2():
    another_string = some_string_entry.get() + " and green eggs and ham"  
    # perform function with entry created from button 1
    print(another_string)


button_step_1 = tk.Button(frame, text="Button 1", command=function_1) 
button_step_2 = tk.Button(frame, text="Button 2", command=function_2)  

button_step_1.pack()
button_step_2.pack()  

frame.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Is there another GUI system that would fit better?

I have tried to use a StringVar to transport the entry as per [this google result](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-return-a-value-from-a-function-that-is-executed-from-the-Tkinter-button-Python-TkInter-development):

```
    from tkinter import * 
     
    root=Tk() 
     
    def method2(): 
        x="Done it !" 
        m.set(x) 
     
    m=StringVar() 
    b1=Button(root, text="Click", command=method2).pack() 
    lb1=Label(root, text="...", textvariable=m).pack() 
     
    root.mainloop()
```

however their example does not involve the string changing between button presses...

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

window = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(window)
def function_1():

    some_string_entry = tk.Entry(frame)
    some_string_entry.pack()

    transportation_string_var.set(some_string_entry.get())


def function_2():
    another_string = transportation_string_var.get() + " and green eggs and ham" 
    print(another_string)


transportation_string_var = tk.StringVar(window)

button_step_1 = tk.Button(frame, text= "Button 1", command=function_1) # creating button 1
button_step_2 = tk.Button(frame, text= "Button 2", command= partial(function_2, transportation_string_var))

button_step_1.pack()
button_step_2.pack()

frame.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I've thought about structuring the GUI workflow differently, but it is difficult as function 1 is opening and presenting a file to the user, the user makes decisions, and then based on those decisions, function 2 changes and saves a file.

I've also thought about using a class, but I am still pretty new and don't understand them well enough to make it work.

Comment: so you just want the entry box to be packed after `button_1` is pressed and want to print the data in the entrybox when `button_2` is pressed? If thats so your code is pretty simple

Answer (score 1):

Using a class that only has one instance, if anyone is searching and finds it useful...?

```
    import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

class frame_1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(window)
        self.some_string_entry = None

    def function_1(self):

        self.some_string_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.some_string_entry.pack()


    def function_2(self):
        another_string = self.some_string_entry.get() + " and green eggs and ham"
        # perform function with entry created from button 1
        print(another_string)

frame_class_instance = frame_1()
button_step_1 = tk.Button(frame_class_instance.frame, text="Button 1", command=frame_class_instance.function_1)
button_step_2 = tk.Button(frame_class_instance.frame, text="Button 2", command=frame_class_instance.function_2)

button_step_1.pack()
button_step_2.pack()

frame_class_instance.frame.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The place that I was messing up earlier was that I forgot to create an instance of frame_1. It concerns me that there will only ever be a single use of this, but hey, at least it doesn't send things to global...?